# Cascade Delete Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables.
Product,  Company, Employee

ProductId of Product table is foregin key for Company
and CompanyId of Company table is foregin key for Employee

So on deleting ProductId from Product table, all the related records in other tables should delete. But I can't touch schema(can't use alter table). How should I write the query in that case..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can't add constraints that propagates the delete, you have to write all the necessary deletes yourself:

```
delete employee where companyid in (select companyid from company c where productid = xxx);
delete company where productid=xxx;
delete product where productid=xxx;
```

Comment: so do I need to write the 3 queries, can't be done in single one?

Comment: Nope. But you could write a stored procedure around these 3 queries.

Comment: I think there is a good reason for that. If you want cascading deletes, make a referential constraint with the "ON DELETE CASCADE" option. But in some cases, you simply would not want that, because the danger of deleting way more than intended is to big. For example, you definitely don't want to delete an invoice item just because someone tries to delete the product that was sold. If there was a "CASCADE" option for the DELETE statement, people would use it without knowing how much damage they cause.

Comment: The downside that I see to this is that nothing forbids another user from adding an employee while query 1 above is running, causing query 2 to bomb out with a foreign key constraint violation.  With foreign keys with cascade delete, that won't be a problem, although the deleting session will hang until the other session commits or rolls back.  What you should do is use both ON DELETE CASCADE and use the SQL above.  (On Delete Cascade is notoriously slow.)

Comment: To make ON DELETE CASCADE run reasonably quickly, you need an index on the foreign key column. Which is good practice anyway for foreign key constraints, even without the ON DELETE CASCADE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try this option. I don't have environment to test this. I guess with some changes it should work at your end.

```
DELETE Product,Company,Employee 
FROM 
user LEFT JOIN items ON product.productid = company.productid 
LEFT JOIN orders ON company.productid = product.productid 
WHERE product.productid = [$productid]
```

Comment: You can not put joins in a delete statement